# JavaScript Charting library - Google Analytics Style

Tags: javascript, canvas, charts

I'm searching for a Javascript library to create line charts like the ones of Google Analytics. When the mouse is over a point, a box shows you the data.

An example is at http://wikirank.com/en

No Flash or Air, only JS and client-side Canvas...

Better if Free...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Edit: If you want a free library, try [Flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/).

[Emprise Charts](http://www.ejschart.com/) is a commercial library that I've seen featured on news sites.

Answer (score 8):

Another option is to use Google's [visualization APIs](http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery.html).It's pretty easy to use, and they have a several options for displaying data. One thing to keep in mind is some of the visualizations require you to send your data to their server, though none of the canvas/svg ones have this requirement.

Answer (score 2):

There's [JS-Charts](http://www.jscharts.com/) which looks pretty awesome.

Or, if you fancy rolling your own you can create your own charting component using [this library](http://www.walterzorn.com/jsgraphics/jsgraphics_e.htm)...

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to Flot, if you are using Prototype.js as JS framework, you can use [Flotr](http://code.google.com/p/flotr/).

Answer (score 0):

Dojo also has something similar, though the example shown doesn't have similar functionalities but can be implemented to behave like the one you want,

http://dojocampus.org/explorer/#Dojox_Charting_2D_Lines,%20Markers,%20No%20Axes,%20Purple%20Theme,%20Custom%20Min%20Max

Answer (score 0):

[Raphael.js](http://raphaeljs.com) is pretty good at making graphs with svg/vml, you have to write some custom code though, but you can make some really nice animation with it, next to that it's compatible with ie6+ (only not with android 2 browsers).